# heroku subdomain wildcard on herokuapp.com

Tags: heroku, subdomain, wildcard

I am running a PHP application on Heroku and am wondering if I can have wildcard subdomains on top of the herokuapp.com hosted subdomain.  For example I have my application running on mysubdomain.herokuapp.com through Heroku, however can I make it so *.mysubdomain.herokuapp.com points still to my server?

I am simply uploading my PHP application to the heroku instance by using 'git push heroku master'

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately what you are trying to achieve is not feasible